# When Integrating Pentaho Kettle into a Java Application, Why is the MongoDB output not working?

Tags: java, mongodb, kettle, karaf

I am new to Pentaho Kettle and I am using the latest version, 6.0. I have created several simple transformations and jobs in Spoon.

I have a Job that runs a transformation that simply pulls data from CSV files, adds a couple fields to each row, and sends the rows to MongoDB. I also have an error step(**Write to Log**) coming off of the **MongoDB Output** step.

The job and transformation run perfectly in Spoon and all rows appear in MongoDB.

However, when I run the Job from my Java App, everything runs perfectly except when it gets to the **MongoDB Output** step. There all the rows go to the **Write to Log** step and there are no errors recorded.

When I take out the **Write to Log** step there still no errors recorded and no rows are written to MongoDB.

I have a MongoDB driver in my classpath and it was also suggested to put the classes folder from the Kettle root into the my classpath becuase MongoDB is an OSGi plugin. This I have done. However, I am still not getting data into mongodb.

Further research shows that the MongoDB plugin is run in a Apache Karaf implementation. Do I need to be running my Java application as a plugin in a Karaf container along with the MongoDB plugin or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

I needed to include the VM argument -**DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=C:\util\kettle\data-integration\system\karaf\system\pentaho** where **C:\util\kettle** is the path on my system.

Note: The MongoDB plugin is running on Apache Karaf. It appears that Pentaho is putting their new plugins in this new folder instead of the **data-integration\plugins** folder as they move from Apache Felix to Apache Karaf. That's also the reason for the VM argument.

I also needed to ensure that the following jars are in my classpath:
*metastore,*
*commons-beanutils,
commons-digester,
commons-logging,
commons-vfs,
js(rhino),
ognl,
log4j,
junit,
guava,
commons-codec,
scannotation,
javassist
pentaho-metaverse-api,
org.apache.felix.main,
pentaho-mongo-utils,
pdi-dataservice-server-plugin,
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1*